# R readr single col_types

Tags: r, dplyr, readr

Is it possible within `readr` package to read in data and specify a single data type across all columns? Similar to `base::read.table` with `colClasses = "character"` or using the `as.is` argument.

Unless the task, data headers, file encoding, etc are well defined ahead of analysis I prefer to write my loaders without changing the datatypes and then process the schema later downstream. Always open to suggestion on how other folks think about things.

Comment: Something that important is probably in the documentation.

Comment: To set all the columns to the same type, read 1 line with `nmax = 1` to get the number of columns, then read the whole thing with `col_types = paste(rep("c", ncol), collapse = "")` (for "character").

Comment: I think asking if **readr** has the ability to recycle column specifications in the same way as `colClasses` in `read.table` is pretty reasonable. I don't see a compact, direct way to do it, but I think it would make a good feature request on github.

Comment: Thanks, yes i checked out the docs as well as the col_types.R file on github but nothing jumped out at me. I agree there are certainly work around but would probably just default back to base functions rather than doing any sort of "trickery" (for reasons of maintainability).

Comment: FWIW, I sort of doubt that Hadley would like the idea of a fully recycled column specification, but he might be open to adding a compact, direct way to tell **readr** to just read everything as character (or another single type).

Comment: In principle, you don't need to worry about `column_types` because they will be imputed from the first 30 rows on the input. For details, check `?read_table`

In case you really want to specify a single data type across all columns, Gregor's answer is pretty good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer. No, this isn't built-in (at this point), the documentation of the `col_types` is quite clear about its capabilities, this isn't one of them. Given the way `col_types` works, implementing this would probably require a brand new argument since a feature is that a "short" `col_types` will be used to restrict the number of columns read.

However, you could write a wrapper:

```
read_table_asis = function(...) {
    n_cols = ncol(read_table(..., n_max = 1))
    read_table(..., col_types = paste(rep("c", n_cols), collapse = ""))
}
```

Comment: ended up going with this solution, despite by reluctance, since it was fewer keystrokes than writing out all the read.table options... thanks!

Answer (score 8):

As of **readr** 0.2.2 we can do something like this to read a csv with all columns as character:

```
read_csv("path/to/file",col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))
```